# How to disable user after 3 unsuccessful login attempts in alfresco?

Tags: alfresco-share

Im using Alfresco community version 5.2 and i have to immediately implement password policy as to disable user after 3 unsuccessful login attempts in alfresco for 1 hr.

can any please help how to proceed

Answer (score 1):

There is webscript which is responsible for login.Below are 2 file which are responsible for the same.You need to maintain counter on server side.Once this counter increases your specified limit.You can call webscript which will disable account.

- login.get.html.ftl
- login.js

How to create repository webscript is explained in below lik.
http://www.krutikjayswal.com/2016/10/alfresco-webscript-spring-webscript.html

Regarding  disabling account, please check below link.You can use this api in javascript controller.
http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/references/API-JS-disableAccount.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried to find out login attempts by storing the counter using javascripts  localStorage object but it will not be globally available, what if user login from some other browser/system after 2 attempts. So i thought of implementing by overriding LoginController and creating a field in database. 

But im not able to understand how to go with this as im new to alfresco. 
Please help me how to implement this feature